# How to write two values on one line in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm new to LISP and just started self learning. I want to print the value of `p` side by side using `write-line`. What I want to see is `p=x`:

```
(setq p 10987)

(write-line "p=")
(write p)
```

the result looks like this:

```
p=
10987
```

I want to achieve `p=10987` in the same line.

Comment: Have you tried `(write "p=")`?

Comment: @psyFi -- be careful when you edit; your last edit removed `(setq p 10897)` from the code block. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `write-line` with [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm); just use `format` alone.

Note that `setq` and `setf` are intended for mutation of *existing* variables; they are not intended to establish new bindings, and the Common Lisp specification does not define any behavior for the posted code. Typically implementations do what you would expect, but don't attempt to define new variables using `setq` or `setf` in code that matters. Some implementations, e.g., SBCL, issue warnings in such cases.

Common ways to establish new bindings include `defvar`, `defparameter`, or `let`:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *p* 10987)
*P*
CL-USER> (format t "*p*=~A~%" *p*)
*p*=10987
NIL
```

Here `defparameter` establishes a binding to `*p*`; `setf` or `setq` could be used to update this binding now. Note that `*p*` has *earmuffs*, which are conventionally used in Common Lisp to indicate dynamically scoped variables.

The first argument to `format` specifies the output destination. If it is `t`, then the output is to `*standard-output*`; if `nil` then `format` returns a string result. You can also specify a particular stream, or an existing string with a fill pointer as destinations. The [`~A`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cda.htm) in the call to `format` is the aesthetic directive, which usually does what you want when your goal is to print a value for a person to read. The [`~%`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cab.htm) directive causes `format` to emit a newline; with this there is no need for `write-line` to be used at all.

Another (more awkward) approach would be to use [`princ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) and [`terpri`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_terpri.htm):

```
CL-USER> (let ((p 10987))
           (princ "p=")
           (princ p)
           (terpri))
p=10987
NIL
```

Here `p` is a locally scoped variable, hence no earmuffs. `princ` is used to print an object in human-readable form, but it does not emit a newline. The arcanely-named `terpri` emits a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq p 10987)
(write-line (format nil "p=~a" p))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you please explain to me that "~a"?

Comment: Function "format" uses special symbols called directives. For example, directives ~s or ~a are replaced by arguments after string, directive ~% creates new line and so on. 
You can find list of all directives here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_(Common_Lisp)#Format_directives

Comment: @userX Learn the basics of format here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#structure-of-format `~A` (or `~a`) is to print argument "Æesthetically".

Comment: Just use `(format t ...)`-> no need to use `write-line`.